# Where to place a PDF file?

Tags: html, file, pdf, path

Let's say I have the following code to display a PDF file:

```
<embed src="file_name.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px">
```

What folder should I place "file_name.pdf" into? Images?

Comment: Put it wherever you want. You just have to reference it correctly in your HTML. As written, this question is very vague and opinion-based, and it is likely to be closed.

Comment: @EdCottrell So for example if it's in app/assets/images, should I write 'src="app/assets/images/file_name.pdf"'?

Comment: That depends on where the HTML file in question is. Are you just asking how to write a relative URL???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you put your file. What matters is that you link it correctly. For example, if you place your pdf file in `/some/file/path/file_name.pdf`, and your page to show the file is in `/some/file.html`, then you would link it with `file/path/file_name.pdf`. Read more about relative URL's [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676525(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So let's say I have a project called "Project", and a "file.pdf" located under `Project/app/assets/images/file.pdf`, and I want to render it on a page called "view.html", under `Project/app/views/pages/view.html`. Would I write `<embed src="../app/assets/images/file.pdf">`?

Comment: No, because `../` means go up a directory. So, what you've written is linking to `Project/app/vies/app/assets/images/file.pdf`. What you SHOULD write is `../../assets/images/file.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

You must present the file path relative to the location of the webpage.

Let's say this is the path: `ParentDirectory / Embedded_Files / pdfs / file_name.pdf`

If the file lies in a folder nested in the parent directory:
`Embedded_Files / pdfs / file_name.pdf`

If your webpage is in another folder in the parent directory, say `ParentDirectory / webpage_files / index.html`, and you need to access `file_path.pdf`, then:

`../ Embedded_Files / pdfs / file_name.pdf`

Use  `../` to indicate you're providing the relative URL from the parent directory.

Or you can provide the absolute URL:  `https://www.example.com/Embedded_Files/pdfs/file_name.pdf`

To be secure, you should choose folder names that cannot be easily guessed, and then disable access to it as well.

Comment: I feel dumb... So let's say I have a project called "Project", and a "file.pdf" located under `Project/app/assets/images/file.pdf`, and I want to render it on a page called "view.html", under `Project/app/views/pages/view.html`. Would I write `<embed src="../app/assets/images/file.pdf">`?

Comment: Yes, if "Project" is the parent directory.